# SQL help, Get the desired output

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Input:

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| row_min | row_max | tCount |
+---------+---------+--------+
|       2 |       4 |      1 |
|       7 |      10 |      2 |
|      13 |      14 |      3 |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

Required Output:

```
+-----+--------+
| row | tcount |
+-----+--------+
|   2 |      1 |
|   3 |      1 |
|   4 |      1 |
|   7 |      2 |
|   8 |      2 |
|   9 |      2 |
|  10 |      2 |
|  13 |      3 |
|  14 |      3 |
+-----+--------+
```

row_min and row_max are expanded in the output with corresponding tcount in their range
This step is required as a part of data transformations, I need to do on a dataset using SQL (data residing in Amazon redshift). I am stuck on this particular step.
Please provide the SQL code required for the same, hopefully limited to using joins and analytic functions.

Comment: Is there any logic standing behind this output?

Comment: @suslov `row_min` and `row_max` are expanded in the output with corresponding `tCount` in their range

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far to generate number sequences?

Comment: Go to loop of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html    and also the repeat section https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repeat.html. I hope you will find the solution

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam In SQL, it is normal to use a numbers table instead of a loop because SQL is intended to be declarative rather than procedural: [Why are numbers tables “invaluable”?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506).

Comment: And redshift is based on Postgres and should have an early version of `generate_series` available from a quick Google. No `lateral` support though so I assume you'd need to join onto the return table of the function called with a range deemed to be likely to be big enough rather than dynamically producing the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a tally table large enough to include numbers as a high as `MAX(row_max)` of your table:

```
WITH Tally AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS n
   FROM (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) x(n)
   CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) y(n)
)
SELECT n, tCount
FROM Tally AS t
INNER JOIN mytable AS m ON t.n >= m.row_min AND t.n <= m.row_max
```

I think Redshift supports simple, non-recursive, CTEs, so the above should work.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1c8e2/7)